# SQL: How to add a column with the minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access-2010, minimum

I would appreciate your support, I'd like to build a SQL qry  to obtain as result an additional comlumn with the minimum value of group of codes based on 2 tables.

For example:I have 2 tables

Table: extract

```
AppCode | Phase |
------------------ 
AB | Phase 2
ABC | Phase 1
ABC | Phase 2
ABCD | Phase 1
ABCE | Phase 3
ABCE | Phase 2
```

Table: Phases

```
PhaseName | Objective
------------------
Phase 1 | 2
Phase 2 | 4
Phase 3 | 24
```

Output expected:

```
AppCode |   PhaseName |  Objective |  MinObjetivo 
------------------
AB |       Phase 2 |        4 |            4
ABC |      Phase 1 |        2 |            2 
ABC |      Phase 2 |        4 |            2 
ABCD |     Phase 1 |        2 |            2
ABCE |     Phase 3 |        24 |           4
ABCE |     Phase 2 |        4 |            4
```

Please Let me know; if with this example is not enough

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT e.appcode, p.phasename, p.objective, m.minobjectivo
FROM extract AS e
JOIN phases AS p ON e.phase = p.phasename
JOIN (SELECT e1.appcode, MIN(p1.objective) as minobjectivo
      FROM extract AS e1
      JOIN phases AS p1 ON e1.phase = p1.phasename
      GROUP BY e1.appcode) AS m
    ON e.appcode = m.appcode
```

This starts out as an ordinary join between `extract` and `phases`, to get the first 3 columns. Then you write a subquery that gets the minimum objective for each appcode, and join this to get the additional column.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae3a8/1)

Here's another way to write it:

```
SELECT e.appcode, p.phasename, p.objective, MIN(p1.objective) AS minobjectivo
FROM extract AS e
JOIN phases AS p ON e.phase = p.phasename
JOIN extract AS e1 ON e1.appcode = e.appcode
JOIN phases AS p1 ON e1.phase = p1.phasename
GROUP BY e.appcode, p.phasename
```

This is similar, but the additional joins are done in the main query instead of a subquery.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae3a8/5)

Comment: BarMar, do you know why with the SQL editor of MsAccess 2010 is not working ???? .... The error message is "Syntax Error in FROM clause"

Comment: No idea, I don't use Access.

Comment: Some versions of SQL don't allow `AS` before aliases in `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: Why does MS Access matter? Your question is tagged for MySQL.

Comment: Sorry Barmar; The problem was for MySQL and is working fine thanks a lot for you support and I am using also MsAccess and I just wanted to reply this scenario as well; but I will post another question for Access.

Comment: I found the solution for MsAccess-2010 version:

SELECT 
e.appcode, 
p.phasename,
p.objective,
m.minobjectivo 

FROM (extract AS e

INNER JOIN Phases AS p ON e.phasename = p.phasename)

INNER JOIN (SELECT e1.appcode, MIN(p1.objective) as minobjectivo 
      FROM extract AS e1 
      INNER JOIN Phases AS p1 ON e1.phasename = p1.phasename
      GROUP BY e1.appcode) AS m 
ON e.appcode = m.appcode;

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a `join`, but with a twist.  Most databases support window functions, and these will do what you want:

```
select e.appcode, p.phasename, p.objective,
       min(p.objective) over (partition by e.appcode) as minObjetivo
from extract e join
     phases p
     on e.phase = p.phasename;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon; its working fine and I also using Ms Access 2010; do you know the correct SQL code?; when I tried to use this one, doesn't work ... The error message is: "missing operator in query expression min(p.objective) over (partition by e.appcode) "